# Sequence contains no records in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
StackTrace = "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__0[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)\r\n   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult]...
```

It was working before all of a sudden not able to get any records from the table using entity framework

Don't know what is the issue it worked fine before haven't made any changes to the edmx file either

```
  public bool SetClientIdForUser(string username, string clientId)
    {
        aspnet_Users aspnetUsers = _objVaccinationContext.aspnet_Users.First(t => t.UserName == username);
        //aspnetUsers.Client_Id = clientId;
        aspnetUsers.Client_id = clientId;
        var entry = _objVaccinationContext.Entry(aspnetUsers);
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        _objVaccinationContext.SaveChanges();
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

**CONNECTION STRING :** `<add name="ChildVaccinationEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ChildVaccinationContext.ChildVaccination.csdl|res://*/ChildVaccinationContext.ChildVaccination.ssdl|res://*/ChildVaccinationContext.ChildVaccination.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=localhost;initial catalog=CVSUAT;user id=sa;password=Password123;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />`

**NOTE:** the first record in my table is the record i want to get so cannot use any other function

Comment: Check directly in the Db to see if there are any records. Maybe even execute the query you see in debug.

Comment: Also Make sure the connection string did not change, if you work in a team, under source control, somebody might have checked-in a different connection string or something.

Comment: there are records in my db and that particular username and clientid are present as well

Comment: COuld it be a problem with the ef4?

Comment: Have you executed the query as @dutzu suggested?

Comment: yes i am at home so changing connection string isn't an option  yes it hasn't changed

Answer (score 2):

You can use FirstOrDefault then check for null

```
aspnet_Users aspnetUsers = _objVaccinationContext.aspnet_Users.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserName == username);

if(aspnetUsers != null)
{

  //do your stuff
return true
}

else
{
return false
}
```

Comment: @vini scartag's right, that's just not possible. If you get the same error, either you're still calling `.First` somewhere else, or you haven't rebuilt your project (which should happen automatically). Please explicitly rebuild your project, start the debugger, and if you do get an exception, look closely where the exception is coming from.

Comment: It is coming in the same function yes i have rebuilt my project

Answer (score 1):

The `First` method of LINQ throws an exception if the filtered sequence does not at least contain one element. So if the `username` is not found within your database, this line of code throws an error. You can use `FirstOrDefault` and check for `null`.

Comment: there are records in my db and that particular username and clientid are present as well

Comment: *The First method of LINQ throws an exception if the filtered sequence does not contain exactly one element.* It is not true. You have mistaken it for `Single()` method. `First` throws an exception if there is not at least one element.

Comment: the first record in my table is the record i want to get so cannot use any other function